# AngularJS push item does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have put all necessary files into a single file. I want to push item into array when the user clicks on a button. Here is the content:

When I click on the button, nothing happens. Also the data is not repeated/looped and `{{}}` is shown in angular which means there is a problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js" ></script>
        <div data-ng-app="App">
            <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
                <ul data-ng-repeat="one in names">
                    <li>{{ one.first }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="text" data-ng-model="Namer.name"/>
        <input type="submit" data-ng-click="AddName()"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var App = angular.module("App", []);

    App.controller("MyController", function($scope){
        $scope.names = [
            { first : "Thomas"},
            { first  : "Geferson"},
            { first  : "Jenny"},
            { first  : "Maria"},
        ];

        $scope.AddName = function(){
            $scope.names.push({
                name : $scope.Namer.name;
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're using the property name `first` in the initial names array, but pushing in an object with the name in a property called `name` in the `AddName` function. That should be `first: $scope.Namer.name;` to match your existing schema.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point..which line should edited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLFgc/)**

```
var App = angular.module("App", []);

App.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
        first: "Thomas"
    }, {
        first: "Geferson"
    }, {
        first: "Jenny"
    }, {
        first: "Maria"
    }];

    $scope.AddName = function () {
        $scope.names.push({
            first: $scope.Namer.name
        });
    };
});
```

You need to move your `data-ng-click` inside Controller.Also you had some syntax issues.That is also i fixed (To work with IE ALSO)

```
<div data-ng-app="App">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="one in names">
            <li>{{ one.first }}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="Namer.name" />
        <input type="submit" data-ng-click="AddName()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MT-Developer also the data-ng-click position

Answer (score 3):

Move your inputs to inside your `MyController` so that it executes code in the scope created by the controller:

```
<div data-ng-app="App">
     <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
         <ul data-ng-repeat="one in names">
                    <li>{{ one.first }}</li>
          </ul>

          <input type="text" data-ng-model="Namer.name"/>
          <input type="submit" data-ng-click="AddName()"/>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Another mistake is that you need to change `name` to `first` to match with your existing object

```
$scope.AddName = function(){
        $scope.names.push({
            first : $scope.Namer.name //change to first and remove the ;
        });
 };
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/e7YZfoTUWb0uZ8ZEzoXh?p=preview)

Comment: But I still do not get my iteration

Comment: @M T - Developer: also try removing the ; at the end of `first : $scope.Namer.name`, that would cause syntax error